# Group By and Append Row in R

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that contains multiple tickers. As new information comes into the market I would like to add the data to the table.

```
df = data.frame(ticker = c(rep("AAPL", 2), rep("SPY", 2)), price = rnorm(4))
print(df)
ticker      price
1   AAPL -0.6039186
2   AAPL -0.1661572
3    SPY -1.1038832
4    SPY  0.1755888

#New prices were discovered. 
df.new = data.frame(ticker = c("AAPL", "SPY"), price = rnorm(2))
print(df.new)
  ticker      price
1   AAPL -0.1527394
2    SPY -0.5448376
```

I would like to insert these at the end of the row for each ticker. The Final  dataframe should look like this.

```
ticker      price
1   AAPL -0.6039186 #original
2   AAPL -0.1661572 #original
3   AAPL -0.1527394 #new
4    SPY -1.1038832 #original
5    SPY  0.1755888 #original
6    SPY -0.5448376 #new
```

I was originally trying

```
df %>% group_by(ticker) %>% rbind(df.new)
```

After the comment I tried this and it worked. Was this the way you were thinking of doing it?

```
df.final = rbind(df, df.new) %>% group_by(ticker) %>% sort(#in my case by date which I opted to leave out in the example)
```

Comment: What did you try? We can help if you get stuck. This is a basic row bind and sort.

Comment: Hi Parfait! Thank you! I think I figured it out from reading your comment. I added some edits. Let me know if I did it write.

Comment: @JordanWrong - yep, looks good to me. There is also `bind_rows` in *dpylr* if you are working in the tidyverse.

Comment: `bind_rows(df, df.new) %>% arrange(ticker, date)` should work. If you're already using `dplyr` and friends, I suggest you use `bind_rows` for this instead of `rbind`; while the latter will work, the `dplyr` version adds explicit safeguards (including reordering columns if they are out of place but still all present, something `rbind` does not handle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the following then realised that r2evans suggested exactly that in a comment already...

```r
library(dplyr)

df = tibble(ticker = c(rep("AAPL", 2), rep("SPY", 2)), price = rnorm(4))

#New prices were discovered. 
df.new = tibble(ticker = c("AAPL", "SPY"), price = rnorm(2))

df %>% bind_rows(df.new) %>% arrange(ticker)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   ticker  price
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 AAPL    1.36 
#> 2 AAPL   -1.19 
#> 3 AAPL   -0.208
#> 4 SPY     0.137
#> 5 SPY    -1.87 
#> 6 SPY     1.51
```